# NHibernate QueryOver Subjective Where?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, queryover

So in SQL I can write a query like this:

```
SELECT
  A,
  B,
  C
FROM
  myTABLE
WHERE
  (@X is NULL OR A = @X) AND
  (@Y is NULL OR B = @Y) AND
  (@Z is NULL OR C = @Z)
```

in order create a single query that returns all entries if no filtering parameters are specified, or a subset if any of them are specified. But how would I go about doing this using Nhibernate's QueryOver? I'm not even fully sure how to do an OR with QueryOvery at all...

Comment: Please, read this first: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-simpleexpressions *(16.2. Simple Expressions)*. There are all the answers. If any issue remains, show what you've done so far... and you will get help here, I am sure ;)

Comment: Thanks for the link. So basically it appears I can't filter based on the parameter (like a shortcut), only the column. So I'd need to use separate statements to do this, like this:
'code'
  var qry = session.QueryOver<obj>();
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(A)) { qry.Where(x => x.a == A); }
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(B)) { qry.Where(x => x.b == B); }
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(C)) { qry.Where(x => x.c == C); }
  List<obj> fileList = qry.List<obj>().ToList();

Comment: `var qry = session.QueryOver<obj>();
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(A)) { qry.Where(x => x.a == A); }
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(B)) { qry.Where(x => x.b == B); }
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(C)) { qry.Where(x => x.c == C); }
 List<obj> data = qry.List<obj>().ToList();`

Comment: I would say, that this is exactly what we need. Because, the evaluation is done on the application side - no need to pass it to SQL. Other words, this resulting code snippet is exactly the right (if not even best) way how to! Great job sir ;)

Comment: What you posted in your comment is the best way to do this. You should add it as an answer and accept it so that it helps people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to subjectively query (based on the parameter), the accepted method would be to build the where clause in pieces as such:

```
var qry = session.QueryOver<obj>(); 
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(A)) { qry.Where(x => x.a == A); } 
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(B)) { qry.Where(x => x.b == B); } 
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(C)) { qry.Where(x => x.c == C); } 
List<obj> data = qry.List<obj>().ToList();
```

So that the final result is the exact query to run for a given set of parameters, rather the generalized SQL query specified in the original post.